# What's wrong with my answer?(Finite Automata)

Tags: computation-theory, finite-automata, deterministic

Quite confused with this problem here regarding finite automata

Consider the finite automaton

```
M=({q0,q1}, {0}, {((q0,0),q1), ((q1,0),q0)}, q0, {q1}).
```

If the alphabet is `{0,1}`, what happens to the machine if the input string contains 1? Modify the FA so that the problem is resolved.

I tried to change the transition function `((q0, 0),q1))` into `((q0,1),q1))`, which from my understanding would make the finite automata correct. Professor says its still wrong. Any help with this?

Comment: It looks like the answer to the first question is that it's undefined. You have to account for all the states and all inputs. Simply modifying one state will still leave two states undefined, so add two more. If this is the entire problem statement, then it looks like it doesn't care what those functions are, so long as they're defined.

Comment: Right now this DFA decides odd-length strings of `0` (regex `0(00)*`). If you change `((q0, 0),q1)` to `((q0, 1),q1)`, this becomes the DFA that decides strings made of `1` followed by zero or more `01`s (regex `1(01)*`). Your prof probably wants a complete DFA, meaning all states have a transition for all inputs. This could mean that a new "dead" state can be added, or it could mean changing the nature of the language. It's unclear from the description of the problem you've provided which the prod might want. Incomplete DFAs aren't "wrong", they just have implicit dead states.

Answer (score 0):

As of now your automata accepts strings that has an odd number of zeroes.
because 2 0's will take you back to the same start state again and q_1
is only on 0 away from q_0.  But this dfa still remains incomplete , as there is no mapping for delta (q_0,1) , delta(q_1,1) So , in-case you encounter a 1, you need to clearly stay in the same place, i.e q0 or q1 since this does not change the number of 0's you have seen up until then